# Obtain name of worksheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to access all of the tabs in a spreadsheet using the following:

```
        rawReturnwb = openpyxl.load_workbook(ValidationsDir)
        for sheet in rawReturnwb.worksheets:
              do something...
```

This works fine.  I then would like to access the worksheet name to use else where in my code.  However when I try access the worksheet name (printing `sheet` to the console) I get:

```
<Worksheet "SheetName">
```

the `type` of sheet is

```
<class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet'>
```

Is there a way that I can just get the worksheet name returned (so my output would be `"SheetName"` only.  Or would I have to convert to string and strip the parts of the string I don't need?

Comment: try `sheet.title`

Comment: @Stacey, not that usually variable starting with a capital letter are for classes. You could rename your directory to `validations_dir` ... and using `dir` is weird to indicate the path of an Excel file :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comment of the question, `sheet.title` is working.

For example, this is some code to get the Worksheet name from a given cell:

```py
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
def get_cell_name(cell:Cell) -> str:
    """Get the name of the Worksheet of a given cell"""
    return cell.parent.title
```

And in the case of the OP, the code could be something like:

```
rawReturnwb = openpyxl.load_workbook(ValidationsDir)
for sheet in rawReturnwb.worksheets:
    # ...
    if sheet.title == "Sheet1":
        continue
    # ...
```

FYI, the names of the variables are weird:

- They should be **lowercase** in Python (according to PEP-8)
- `ValdiationsDir` is weird, for the path of an Excel File
- `rawReturnwb` could be renamed to `book` for example